# Why there is always a .collect() after a .distinct()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Beginner for spark. Often see .distinct().collect() structure. What might be the intrinsic reason to have the collect() function right after the distinct() function?

Comment: `distinct()` just will remove all the duplicates. `collect()` will bring all elements to the main memory. Thus both together collect all unique elements. That is all, nothing special. Why your code does that, only you and your team may know.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess that it depends on the data structure. If your data structure is non-strict, like a `Stream`, the order of `distinct` and `collect` is significant.

Comment: Well of course, and in this case it surely is an **RDD** or a **Dataset** _(in any case the collect that exists in other collections is different, thus the order is always significant)_. But what does that has to do with my comment? I just stated that there is nothing special in calling the two methods together, is just like calling any other two methods together, which is just like calling any method. That is just how you build a program.

Comment: it's not true that there is always a `collect` after a `distinct`. In fact these methods have nothing in common, may be a coincidence that have have always saw them together

Answer (score 6):

`distinct` is a transformation. This means that it is not executed immediately, but only when an action is called.

`collect` is an action. Calling the `collect` method causes all previous transformations to be run.

Outside Spark calling `distinct` after `collect` could increase the memory footprint of your program, because the program will generate also the duplicate elements. In Spark, calling `distinct` after `collect` could also make your entire program fail.

You can find more explanations here: https://dzone.com/articles/getting-lazy-with-scala

Answer (score 3):

Spark leverages the concept of 'lazy evaluation'.  Lazy evaluation means that Spark will wait until the very last moment to execute a graph of computation instructions, generally in order to look for ways to enhance the execution plan.  Lazy evaluation includes the concepts of transformations and actions.  A transformation (such as `distinct()`, `sort()`, `sum()`) will be noted by Spark and built into a logical plan.  This plan is called a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).  We need to call an action to get Spark to execute the DAG.  Examples of actions include `count()`, `show()`, or `collect()`.  Actions are basically anything that brings the result of our data transformations back to the native object in the respective language, in this case Python.

In the case of your example, Spark doesn't actually execute the DAG when you call `distinct()`.  It executes the DAG when you call an action after distinct, such as `distinct().collect()` or `distinct().show()` or `distinct().count()`.  Also, `collect()` is simply a function that returns the DataFrame as a Python List of Row objects as specified here... [`collect()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.collect)  .  You can choose from other actions to follow `distinct()`, `collect()` is just a frequently used example in tutorials because it shows the structure of the Row in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this.

`collect` is an action. As mentioned above, Spark executes all the operations leading up to the beginning (if caching is not used) and return the result when you call `collect`. However, you saw the reason why you saw `distinct` before `collect` could be that `collect` returns the results to the driver program and to limit the result, it selects only distinct values and then returns to the driver. This way there will be less number of records to be fetched and it can avoid `OutOfMemory` errors.

There is no other reason why you see these two methods together. Please, note that it is just a coincidence that you saw these two together. I have never used them together in any of my projects yet.